# how can measure on test code using javancss maven plugin

Tags: java, maven

I’m using javancss maven plugin for measuring lines of codes and cyclomatic complexity. 
I can not find the way of configuring the plugin in order to analyze test code as well.

This is a fragment of pom.xml file:

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>javancss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.1</version>
     <configuration>
       <includes>
         <include>**/Exam.java</include>
         <include>**/Topic.java</include>
         <include>**/TopicSequenceTest.java</include>
         <include>**/TestWithMockObjects.java</include>
       </includes>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

This is the project structure:

```
src
  main
    ...
  test
    ...
```

This is the way I use it:

```
mvn javadoc:javadoc javancss:report jxr:jxr jxr:test-jxr
```

I think it doesn’t work because ** is representing src/main, then it can not include any java file under src/test
But I cannot find the solution.

Thank you in advance